# How to click the dropdown option which is visible only by hovering action using playwrite python script

Tags: playwright-python

Playwright python script for action: click "To CSV" is dropdown visible only by hovering over the text "Export":

[image]

HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got you

This is how i currently do it on my Playwright script

```
page.type("#react-select-2-input", "January\n")                         
page.type("#react-select-3-input", "1\n")                                
page.type("#react-select-4-input", "1998\n\n")  
page.click("#CSS SELECTOR EXPORT TAB", "MENU ITEM HERE\n")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).